# BIRT Reporting using scripting datasource in Spring MVC Application

Tags: hibernate, maven, spring-mvc, crystal-reports, birt

I want to use Reporting tool in my spring mvc web application. Can anyone suggest me which is better....**Crystal report** or **BIRT**?

I have downloaded dynamic project from web and successfully done sample reports using Crystal Report,but it is another project and I am not able to integrate it with my web application because of maven dependencies are not available for crystal reports jars.

So I am looking forward toward BIRT and I want to use Scripting datasource.

Comment: can you please elaborate?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Very Glad..Finally achived using by going step by step:-
 http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/ba-birt-viewer-java-webapps/index.html
 and this :- http://developer.actuate.com/community/forum/index.php?/files/file/473-scripted-data-source-using-json/

Answer (score 0):

When you use BIRT eclipse editor, by default all your datasource info are part of the report design itself. When you use the design inside a Spring app, you can leave it that way (this is the easiest solution), but if you wish to pass it somehow, the problem is much more complicated, as BIRT engine supports a lot of custom parametrs that can be passed to it, while the documentation is not very good.

As for the integration itself, you can look at: https://spring.io/blog/2012/01/30/spring-framework-birt
Personally, I'd do it a little bit different, but maybe this is what you are looking for.

Comment: I already refered that link.Actually in Birt Script, I want to straight to call ServiceImpl and get the data from DAO, although it not good solution, but cannot break the existing architecture.